# Not sure how to deal with repeating decimals in C

Tags: c, numbers, rounding, cs50

```
int number = round(2/3);
printf("%i", number);
```

the output is

```
0
```

I expected to get 1 as 0.6 recurring should round up - i know for sure that the problem is with recurring decimals as they are always rounded down - I'm not sure how to round up in this kind of scenario.

Comment: The expression `2/3` is one of ***integer*** division, and will be zero. Try `2.0/3`.

Comment: Yes thats perfect, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  double number = round(2.0/3.0);
printf("%0.f", number);
}
```

Output = 1

**You can use double or float for rounding numbers**

Answer (score 1):

use `double` or `float` number. in definition and in `printf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double number = (double)2/3;
    printf("%.f", number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without floating point calculations, the following will round to nearest using just integer division:

```
int a = 2;
int number = (a + 1) / 3;    // = 1
```

In general, rounding `a / b` to the nearest integer is equivalent to truncating `(a + b / 2) / b`.